# How to change the temp directory for RSelinium?

Tags: temporary-files, rselenium, rethrow, rsdriver

Is there a way to manually designate where RSelinium creates this temp .bat file?

```
Error in rethrow_call(c_processx_exec, command, c(command, args), pty,  : 
  create process 'C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\1\...\file#######.bat' (system error 5, Access is denied.
) @win/processx.c:1040 (processx_exec)
```

What would be nice is something like:

```
temp_file <- "Some/Directory/of/my/choosing/file123456789.bat"
rD <- RsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "###.#.####.##", port=####L, TempDirWhatever = temp_file)
```

sadly, it doesn't seem that simple.